# maintaining even stroke when trimming off bleed marks after printing

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs6, stroke, bleed

I am creating a publication that has black and white borders (strokes) that bleed out to the edge of the page. I have created a stroke that is 5.4 width around the boxes and would like to make sure that when it goes through the printing process the 5.4 stroke is maintained. I have created a black shape behind for the black borders that stretches out to the bleed see image below. I have done a test print and when I trim off the bleed marks the stroke is not even around the page :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is, in my opinion, a ridiculous amount of precision to expect. There's a *reason* one never sees things perfectly aligned to page edges in print pieces. The process is *not* acutely precise. There's **always** some variation. Even the best print houses can't be 100% accurate 100% of the time. There are myriad things which can alter a print from humidity, to stock being used, to barometric pressure.... One should design understanding the overall limitations of the reproduction process. If you've *manually* trimmed things, then perhaps you weren't as precise as you think you were.

Comment: So.. you need to either accept that there *will be* some variation.. or redesign so the lack of precision is not a factor.

Comment: @scott Agreed, but the image of the test print does look like the trim is way off.  If that's an A4 landscape page, the border looks about 15mm one side, 5mm the other.  Precision better than that should be possible, shouldn't it?

Comment: End use, home printers, have a gripper edge - the edge used to actually grab the paper and pull it though the printer. This gripper edge has a larger margin than then other three sides.

Comment: @Scott hi scott thanks for your advice. The border was noticeably uneven when printed it. I know there are a number of factors to consider so was seeking advice for some helpful tips. These are test prints and they are an A5 publication which got printed on an A4 page. I will try to print  on A3 and maybe make the bleed 5mm instead of 3mm to see if that helps.

Comment: What are you running prints on? If it's an end use home printer there is no bleed. Adjusting the bleed isn't going to matter.

Comment: Are you talking about the white stroke or the black margin. The white stroke has an even thickness but the margin is unequal. Does it look correct before trimming? Have you considered that creep will be a factor when trimmed if this is a booklet? Also if that is a two-page spread you seem to have forgotten the inside margin?